# how to look at (aim) a prefab in unity 2d project

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to aim 2d prefabs (they spawn random). I want to aim the nearest  prefab that come near my object.

This not work:

```
 Vector2 direction = target.position - transform.position;
 float angle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
 Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);
 transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotation, 
                                       speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

any idea?

[image: this is full code]

[image: Here is what i want]

Comment: It's a bit tough to understand your intent here - do you think you could supplement your question with a diagram of what you're trying to achieve, so it's easier to see the goal of your code?

Comment: @Serlite edited my question ( added a picture that what i want), i want my main Object Lookat the nearest Prefab –

Comment: All right, so does that mean that you're already able to identify which object is the closest (which I presume is stored in `target.position`), and the only part you're having trouble with is the rotation?

Comment: @Serlite when i put my prefab into transform target, it doesnt look at my prefabs that spawn randomly

Comment: Please use actual copy/pasted code and not an image/screenshot of code.  Otherwise it's very difficult to help because we can't copy/paste your code to try it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that should get you started. 
Whenever you `Instantiate` a target, add it to a list. Let's call it `allTargets` (make sure to add the instantiated object, not the prefab).  Now the only thing you have to do is find the closest `target` in that list.

```
public List<Transform> allTargets;

void Start()
{
    allTargets = new List<Transform>();
}

void Update () {
    Transform closestTarget = GetClosestTarget(allTargets);        
    Quaternion targetRotation = GetRotationTo(closestTarget);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, targetRotation, speed * Time.deltaTime);
}

Quaternion GetRotationTo(Transform target)
{
    Vector3 dir = target.position - transform.position;
    float angle = Mathf.Atan2(dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    return Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);
}

Transform GetClosestTarget(List<Transform> targets)
{              
    Transform closest = null;

    float minDistance = float.MaxValue;
    foreach (var t in targets)
    {
        float distance = Vector2.Distance(t.position, transform.position);
        if(distance < minDistance)
        {
            minDistance = distance;
            closest = t;
        }
    }
    return closest;
}
```

Comment: just a quest, how to add Instantiate objects in allTargets?i have another script that create objects. this is the code prntscr.com/kp0u83

Comment: In your `Spawner` script [get a reference](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/how-communicate-between-scripts-and-gameobjects) to the `Player` script and use that to add objects to the list. `GameObject nextTarget = Instantiate(...); ` 
        `player.allTargets.Add(nextTarget.transform);`

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're able to find the nearest game object and set it in `target.position`. Now change your script to this:

```
void Update () 
{
    Vector2 direction = target.position - transform.position;
    float angle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    Quaternion newQuaternion = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, angle));
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, newQuaternion, speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

**Note that:** Your game object that aiming to prefabs, must look at right x-axis when the rotation in `(0,0,0)` (like the image)

[image]

I hope it helps you